Split screen function before 1970
I know the story about Engelbard and his presentation, in which a proto-window mode for text output was demonstrated.
But. Was this really the first time multi-window mode was used? CAD had a screen divided into a drawing field and an on-screen keyboard in the 1960s.

I imagine that some CAD software from the 1960s might well have been able to split the screen in half and output two drawings on one screen. It could, but did it? Does anyone know of examples of splitting the screen into two (with the same type of content) before Engelbard's presentation?

Dividing the screen into sections with different types of content is indeed a very conditional thing. That's why I'm asking about cases of splitting the screen into sections where there would be different content of the same type. For example, two chapters of one book, two electrical diagrams, two maps, and so on.

By by understanding, some storage tubes were partitioned into multiple distinct "erase" zones; I can easily imagine the usefulness of having a tube with a 75/25 split, with the 25 zone used to show status information without having to erase the 75 zone.

I've never heard of a storage tube with multiple erase zones, but I seem to recall that some tubes (Tektronix?) had a non-storage display mode, in which text could be displayed (by continuously refreshing it like on a conventional CRT) without actually storing it in the tube. This would serve much the same function.

"CAD software from the 1960s " I'm not sure if I should smile or cry, and why :)) Serious, CAD software in the 60's were stacks of punch cards. Graphic screens were so incredible uncommon that no engineer would have one, nor know for what. One codes a circuit as a series of connections. Device A pin B connected to C/D and for multiple connected devices more cards (like A/B to X/Y) were added. That input was all needed and all handled for automatic routing. And already that task would need the biggest machiens available at the time.

@Raffzahn "Graphic screens were so incredible uncommon that no engineer would have one, nor know for what." Have you heard anything about Digidraphics and/or DAC-1?

@Arseniy One of the most published early 2250 uses. But note that for one, it was only started in late 1965 and continued to be a research project GM's Warren, Mi, research center until at least 1968 (see various publications at the time). Not at least due the fact that it needed an IBM 360/50 or /65 just to operate them. Those were the biggest Computers IBM sold at the time. All at a price tag what today might be two digit millions. So exactly the definition of "incredible uncommon". Practical CAD with screen graphical in/output only emerged in the mid 1970s. Anything before is research.

@Arseniy Well, you might want to consider reading the very pages you cite. Like that the project worked at that time on punch cards. After all, it's hard to use a display system before it was first delivered to customer, or can it? In case of the 2250 that's 1965 - likewise for the used 360/50 computer, first delivered in 8/65. Same goes for the CDC 270 system (1967) using a 1965 computer. All of that is hardware without software. Which needed tie to develop, and all of that was pure research, not practical usage.

@Arseniy Last but not least, if you think that some random web page, citing information from wiki is authoritative, it makes not much sense to ask here and dismiss information given by people who have had access to those machines. So thanks for knowing exactly about my knowledge in that fiels. So please watch your language.

@Arseniy On a side note and to give a somewhat comprehensive overview of the mid to late 1960s state of research (not usage), a read of this article in general and the last section about DAC-1 might be useful. Definitely more useful than than second hand Wiki quotes

Some of the later Tek storage tube terminals did have multiple erase zones, but not until later than this asks about.

@Raffzahn Haha, to "have had access to those machines"
you must be a very old man. 2024-1968+20(
for college education)=76 years old al least!
If you are not a 76-year-old man, then in this matter we are equal in the possibilities of obtaining information - we will use both a “random web page” and “quoting information from a wiki”.

@Arseniy: That's not entirely accurate. When I started college, almost none of their equipment was particularly new, and some was quite old, including some that I'm pretty sure went back to the late '50s or very early '60s.

@Arseniy Well, your calculation is a bit off and misleading, but yes, I'm retired by now, have seen one or two computers since when I started and still keep a somewhat reasonable number at home or in close proximity - including early vector stuff :))

Yes, at least sort of. For example, here's shot of a display from a 1966 film about the (then quite new) Plato teaching system.

As we can see, the top half is questions and answers that make up the test, and the bottom half guidelines about the test criteria.
Reference
https://youtu.be/_zvD3okZ640

You are awesome!
